# QnA Maker - Unable to Collaborate with others

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently using a free trial version of Azure to be able to create a QnA service as a PoC at work.  I have created one and am now looking to collaborate with colleagues so we can provide a full assessment of the tool. I have followed the How To Guide '[Collaborate on your knowledge base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/collaborate-knowledge-base)', but found that when the person I have added as an Owner (or Contributor, as I tried both) logs in to their free Azure account, they are unable to see the knowledge base.

If they go to '[Create a knowledge base](https://www.qnamaker.ai/Create)', whilst they are able to select both their own Default Directory and mine, if they select mine, when they go to select an Azure QnA service, they are unable to see mine, only services they have created.

Within Azure Active Directory, I can see the individual with a User Type of Guest and when I click into the detail of their account, I can see that the value for *Invitation accepted* is set to Yes. I added them within Access control (IAM) and can see that their Role is 'Owner' and the Scope is 'This resource'.

If anyone can provide any explanation as to why this still isn't working or how my colleague can best test whether it is working as expected, then it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try asking your colleagues to sign out and back again, that did work for my colleagues.

In our case, we have an Azure Active Directory group that allows to have access to some of the QnAMaker Cognitive Services and therefore, to the Knowledge Bases.

Colleagues that didn't see any of the KBs, even though they were members of that group, didn't accept the invitation. So, I had to send it again to each one of them. But, even after accepting the invitation they couldn't see any of the KBs.

Right after one of these colleagues sign out and back again, he got the list of KBs in the QnAMaker.